# Laravel policies using many to many relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-10, laravel-permission

well, I'm working on a little project in which I'm using `Many to Many` relationship (users to comments by example). I'm trying to validate something, what if this auth user owns this comment? If I own this model, then I want to be able to modify it or delete it.
That's the doubt I have.

I'm trying to be able to modify or delete a model in my Policy, but what I want to validate is if I own it or not in a Many to Many relationship.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, you need to ask a question as should be asked. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how question should be asked how it would attract people to answer it. Personally I like to advice [this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (also found near the bottom of the linked SO page above). Secondly, shouldn't that be one to many relation (as in one user can have many comments)?

Comment: Can you add your sample code and more context ?